# embedded ruby in css id of form_for text_area

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a text_area in a rails form helper:

```
<%= form_for(@comment, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Comment...", class: "common", 
id: "comments-@post.id"%>
  <span><%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, @post.id %></span>
  <%= f.submit "Post Comment", class: "comment-submit btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to add an id number to the text_area's css id, so that once translated it is something like `id="comments-1"` or `id="comments-42"`

In order to do this I need to use some embedded ruby as the id number is stored in the variable @post.id, however I'm getting an error because I'm putting embedded ruby: (`@post.id`) into more embedded ruby: (`<%= f.text_area ... %>`)

is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Anyone who down voted please tell me why so I can improve my future questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `id: "comments-@post.id"` with `id: "comments-#{@post.id}"`

Comment: Not sure why this answer was flagged, but it is correct.  Essentially, what you're doing wrong is you're not escaping the variable from the string.  The "@" symbol in your case is basically appearing as just another character in the string, and only by adding the "#{ }" around it, are you telling ruby to replace that with the value of @post.id